# When not to use <=> instead of = in MariaDB/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null, mariadb, comparison-operators

Is there any reason to use `=` instead of [`<=>`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/null-safe-equal/) in MariaDB/MySQL? It seems that the `=` operator is only desirable if the null is desirable for result of the expression.

Are there any consequences of replacing every `=` with `<=>`? Even if both operands can never be null (for which the behaviour should remain the exact same)?

Comment: When you consider the SQL meaning of `NULL` as no value, its meaning in equality operations is a little odd, however there are cases where `<=>` make sense. Some `JOIN`s will be have rather differently with `<=>`  rather than `=`. I'd keep to using `<=>` as an exceptional case rather than the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the meaning of `NULL` is quite unclear. There are many articles in the Internet about how people interpret it.

Therefore, using `<=>` could just add to the confusion and you risk than other developers may not understand it well. It strongly deviates from the standard behavior most people expect from queries. I would suggest you avoid it unless there are strong reasons why to use it.

Comment: It probably also worth mentioning that there is a standardised operator `IS DISTINCT FROM` that does the same.

Comment: @zerkms I think you should add your comment as an answer, since that should be the right way of phrasing the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b  -- Always NULL (which is usually treated as False) if either is NULL
a <=> b  -- True if _both_ are NULL
```

If both columns are declared `NOT NULL`, there is no use to use `<=>`.

In almost all other cases, your logic is not going to care.

I almost never see anyone using `<=>`.